# How to install prometheus operator and collect the metrics from remote Thanos that install on deferent kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

There is any way to install Thanos on Kubernetes cluster and collect metrics from remote prometheus operator on different Kubernetes cluster? How can I configure the Thanos collect the data from the remote prometheus operator pod?

I am using with Kubernetes 1.12.8 on AWS.

Comment: I thought it was a joke at first but this is really called Thanos.

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/

Answer (score -1):

[thanos](https://thanos.io/getting-started.md),You need to install the thanos sidecar in your clusters, this thanos side car expose store API which can be exposed to other clusters-centralised cluster. There are some deployment model in below links[Architecture](https://improbable.io/blog/thanos-architecture-at-improbable) and [Getting started](https://improbable.io/blog/thanos-prometheus-at-scale)

Comment: may you add the relevant parts to your answer so that if the linked page changes we can still see the solution. Welcome on stackoverflow.